# INSERT INTO values (...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with multiple values

Tags: mysql, insert

Will this work? (i dont have a mysql server available to test >.< )

mytable:
myid : integer/primary key
mydata : text

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1,"new row"),(2,"brand new row"),(3,"yup another new row"), [.....more and more coma-separated parentheses with values], (1000,"guess what? yes new row") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mydata = "dang, this row already exists!";
```

Comment: what is the key? is the ID the primary key? if so, can you get a duplicate in the query? ON DUPLICATE KEY works only for unique values or key combinations

Comment: yes "myid" is the primary key. just assume there are already some rows in the table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will work, but it is advisable to explicitly name the columns first:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
  (myid, mydata)
   VALUES (1,"new row"),(2,"brand new row"),(3,"yup another new row")
```

Also, single quotes are a little more syntactically portable, though MySQL will handle them correctly.

```
   VALUES (1,'new row'),(2,'brand new row'),(3,'yup another new row')
```

Note, if you already have values in `mytable`, you may encounter primary key collisions for `id`. You will need to decide what action should be taken in that circumstance, and apply `ON DUPLICATE KEY` accordingly.

Comment: thank you for your answer Michael! (i'll accept it as soon as i'm able to)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why not:

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      col_name=expr
        [, col_name=expr] ... ]
```

from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html. There's even an example [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and documentation Mr Eder!!! (Michael was a bit faster though ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would. But if your running really large SQL statements - be careful of hitting the maximum SQL size (default is 1Mb I think) you may start to get some odd mysql errors when hitting this length

Comment: Yup that's correct. It is max_packet_size or max_allowed_packet if i remember correctly...